# canvas to WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl

I tried to study WebGL, but I have nothing.
I do not want to use the library, they are too big.
I wrote what I want on the canvas, help me to do it on WebGL

https://jsfiddle.net/g9tx903c/

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="200"></canvas>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function DrawPoint(x, y, size, blur, opacity) {
        var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

        var halfSize = size / 2;

        var radgrad = ctx.createRadialGradient(halfSize + x, halfSize + y, 0, halfSize + x, halfSize + y, halfSize);
        radgrad.addColorStop(blur, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, ' + opacity +')');
        radgrad.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)');
        ctx.fillStyle = radgrad;
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, size, size);
    }


    function DrawcGradient() {
        var w = 500;
        var h = 200;

        var pointR = w / 2;
        var x = (w / 2);
        var y = (h / 2);

        var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
        var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(x, y, 0, x, y, pointR);
        grd.addColorStop(0, '#5A6977');
        grd.addColorStop(1, '#000');
        ctx.fillStyle = grd;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    }


    DrawcGradient();
    DrawPoint(50, 100, 50, 0.5, 0.2);
    DrawPoint(70, 10, 150, 0.93, 0.2);
</script>
```

Comment: You could start using the [HelloWorld](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html) example.

Comment: Why do you want to use WebGL? What are your goals?

Comment: canvas does not work quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just happens to fall into a domain I am catching up on again. Maybe not quite what you want but you can remove all the 2D canvas stuff and just keep the webGL stuff.

This demo mixes 2D and 3D canvas interfaces to get high performance GPU processing on 2D canvas content.

The fragment shader does the work of creating the gradients near bottom of code called `FragmentShader`

Radial gradients are created by calculating the distance from the center and getting a value 0 to 1. I use this value to get the 3 gradients. To change the sharpness of the gradients I multiply, pull down and clamp the values.

eg the big circle near mouse is 1 at center and 0 away. I multiply by 350 to give 350 to 0. then I pull down by 270 to give 80 to -270, then I clamp to 0 and 1. The result is a sharp gradient.

I position the circles on a line from a point just at the top of the canvas and one near the mouse the other further along the line.

There is a lot of boiler plate stuff and I am a little over it today so you will have to nut out the rest.

Very easy to convert to all webGL. Just remove all the canvas mouse stuff up the top. Create an image and call `startWebGL(image)` Add `webGL` canvas (after you create it in `startWebGL` function) to the document body and call at least once the  function `webGLRender` to set the shader variables and  render a frame.

> **Warning** the shaders have high level directive and can not be used without supporting code. To use with other setups remove the `#` infront of all `uniform` and `attribute` variables in shaders. Ie `#uniform vec2 mouse;` becomes `uniform vec2 mouse;`

```js
//==================================================================================================
// The following code is support code that provides me with a standard interface to various forums.
// It provides a mouse interface, a full screen canvas, and some global often used variable 
// like canvas, ctx, mouse, w, h (width and height), globalTime
// It should not be used as an example of how to write a canvas interface.
// By Blindman67
const U = undefined;
const RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME = 100;
var onresize; // demo use this to do your thing
var w,h,cw,ch,canvas,ctx,mouse,createCanvas,resizeCanvas,setGlobals,globalTime=0,resizeCount = 0; 
createCanvas = function () {  // create 2D display canvas
    var c,cs; 
    cs = (c = document.createElement("canvas")).style; 
    cs.position = "absolute"; 
    cs.top = cs.left = "0px"; 
    cs.zIndex = 1000; 
    document.body.appendChild(c); 
    return c;
}
resizeCanvas = function () {
    if (canvas === U) { 
        canvas = createCanvas(); 
    } 
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth; 
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight; 
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
    if (typeof setGlobals === "function") { 
        setGlobals(); 
    } 
    if (typeof onresize === "function"){ 
        resizeCount += 1; 
        setTimeout(debounceResize,RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME);
    }
}
function debounceResize(){ 
    resizeCount -= 1; 
    if(resizeCount <= 0){ 
        onresize();
    }
}
setGlobals = function(){ 
    cw = (w = canvas.width) / 2; 
    ch = (h = canvas.height) / 2; 
    mouse.updateBounds(); 
}
mouse = (function(){
    function preventDefault(e) { e.preventDefault(); }
    var mouse = {
        x : 0, y : 0, w : 0, alt : false, shift : false, ctrl : false, buttonRaw : 0, over : false, bm : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3], 
        active : false,bounds : null, crashRecover : null, mouseEvents : "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover,mousewheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(",")
    };
    var m = mouse;
    function mouseMove(e) {
        var t = e.type;
        m.x = e.clientX - m.bounds.left; m.y = e.clientY - m.bounds.top;
        m.alt = e.altKey; m.shift = e.shiftKey; m.ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
        if (t === "mousedown") { m.buttonRaw |= m.bm[e.which-1]; }  
        else if (t === "mouseup") { m.buttonRaw &= m.bm[e.which + 2]; }
        else if (t === "mouseout") { m.buttonRaw = 0; m.over = false; }
        else if (t === "mouseover") { m.over = true; }
        else if (t === "mousewheel") { m.w = e.wheelDelta; }
        else if (t === "DOMMouseScroll") { m.w = -e.detail; }
        if (m.callbacks) { m.callbacks.forEach(c => c(e)); }
        if((m.buttonRaw & 2) && m.crashRecover !== null){ if(typeof m.crashRecover === "function"){ setTimeout(m.crashRecover,0);}}        
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    m.updateBounds = function(){
        if(m.active){
            m.bounds = m.element.getBoundingClientRect();
        }
    }
    m.addCallback = function (callback) {
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            if (m.callbacks === U) { m.callbacks = [callback]; }
            else { m.callbacks.push(callback); }
        } else { throw new TypeError("mouse.addCallback argument must be a function"); }
    }
    m.start = function (element, blockContextMenu) {
        if (m.element !== U) { m.removeMouse(); }        
        m.element = element === U ? document : element;
        m.blockContextMenu = blockContextMenu === U ? false : blockContextMenu;
        m.mouseEvents.forEach( n => { m.element.addEventListener(n, mouseMove); } );
        if (m.blockContextMenu === true) { m.element.addEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault, false); }
        m.active = true;
        m.updateBounds();
    }
    m.remove = function () {
        if (m.element !== U) {
            m.mouseEvents.forEach(n => { m.element.removeEventListener(n, mouseMove); } );
            if (m.contextMenuBlocked === true) { m.element.removeEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault);}
            m.element = m.callbacks = m.contextMenuBlocked = U;
            m.active = false;
        }
    }
    return mouse;
})();
/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js end **/
function display(){ 
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;           // reset alpha
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    if(webGL !== undefined){
        webGLRender();
    }
}
function update(timer){ // Main update loop
    globalTime = timer;
    display();  // call demo code
    requestAnimationFrame(update); 
}
// END of boilerplate stuff.

/* ***************************************************************************************************
The following functions are helpers for Shader variables. Rather than having to type all the mumbo 
jumbo to locate shader variable and then store the location ID getVariables and getLocations does
it for you. uniform and attribute variable that are prefixed with # are can used via the gl.locs.name
(no space between # and variable type #attribute is good  # attribute is bad)

For example 
  #uniform vec3 myVec;  // the shader source code
Is located and given the name myVec in gl.locs  and can be set in javascript 
  gl.uniform3f(gl.locs.myVec, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8);  //
  
Please not that this makes shaders source code none standard and will not complie as is without these 
functions . Just remove the # 
*************************************************************************************************** */
const VAR_TYPES = ["attribute","uniform"];
const VAR_LOCATE_FUNC = {attribute : "getAttribLocation", uniform : "getUniformLocation"}
// get # delimited variables from shader source 
function getVariables(script,types){
    VAR_TYPES.forEach(f => {
        if(types.items === undefined){  types.items = []; }
        script = script.replace(new RegExp("#" + f+".+;","g"), str => {
            var data = str.replace(/  /g," ").split(" ");
            types.items.push({use : f , type : data[1] , name : data[2].replace(";","")});
            return str.substr(1);
        })
    })
    return  script;
}
// get location IDs for shader variables
var getLocations = function(gl,shaders){
    var locs = {};
    shaders.variables.items.forEach(v => { locs[v.name] = gl[VAR_LOCATE_FUNC[v.use]](shaders.program, v.name); });
    return locs;
}
/* end of var heplers ***************************************************************************** */
// creates vertex and fragment shaders 
function createProgramFromScripts( gl, ids) {
    var shaders = [];
    var variables = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i += 1) {
        var script = shadersSource[ids[i]];
        if (script !== undefined) {
            var shader = gl.createShader(gl[script.type]);
            var source = getVariables(script.source,variables)
            gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
            gl.compileShader(shader);
            shaders.push(shader);  
        }else{
            throw new ReferenceError("*** Error: unknown script ID : " + ids[i]);
        }
    }
    var program = gl.createProgram();
    shaders.forEach((shader) => {  gl.attachShader(program, shader); });
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    gl.locs = getLocations(gl,{ program : program,variables : variables});  
    return program;
}
// setup simple 2D webGL image processor
var webGL;
function startWebGL(image) {
  webGL = document.createElement("canvas");
  webGL.width = image.width;
  webGL.height = image.height;
  var gl = webGL.gl = webGL.getContext("webgl");
  var program = createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["VertexShader", "FragmentShader"]);
  gl.useProgram(program);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.locs.texCoord);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.locs.texCoord, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.createTexture());
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
  gl.uniform2f(gl.locs.resolution, webGL.width, webGL.height);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.locs.position);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.locs.position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  setRectangle(gl, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
}
function setRectangle(gl, x, y, width, height) { // set draw rectangle
  var x1 = x + width;
  var y1 = y + height;
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([ x, y, x1, y, x, y1, x, y1, x1, y, x1, y1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}
var shadersSource = {
    VertexShader : {
        type : "VERTEX_SHADER",
        source : `
            // the # is a higher level directive to indicate that the variable needs to 
            // be loacted as value set or read
            #attribute vec2 position;
            #attribute vec2 texCoord;
            #uniform vec2 resolution;
            varying vec2 u_texCoord;  // varying means this is moved to the frag shader
            float aspect = resolution.x/resolution.y;
            varying float aspect1;
            void main() {
                vec2 zeroToOne = position / resolution;
                vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;
                vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;
                gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
                u_texCoord = vec2(texCoord.x ,texCoord.y / aspect);
                aspect1 = aspect;
            }`
    },
    FragmentShader : {
        type : "FRAGMENT_SHADER",
        source : `
            // the # is a higher level directive to indicate that the variable needs to 
            // be loacted as value set or read        
            precision mediump float;
            #uniform sampler2D u_image;
            #uniform vec4 backDark;  // the background dark colour
            #uniform vec4 backLight; // backgroun light colour
            #uniform vec4 ringCol;  // rings colour
            #uniform vec2 lightLoc;  // location of point from which to project second ring
            #uniform vec2 mouse;     // location of big ring
            varying float aspect1;
            varying vec2 u_texCoord;  // texture coord for all mapping and comes from the 
                                      // vertext shader. If you change the name here 
                                      // change it in the vert shader
            float dist;               // used for background gradient
            vec4 pixelCol;            // to hold the final pixel colour
            vec2 gradCenter = vec2(0.5,0.25); // location of background gradient center
            vec2 secondRing = lightLoc+ (mouse - lightLoc) * (1.2 + distance(mouse,lightLoc));

            
            void main() {
                pixelCol = texture2D(u_image, vec2(u_texCoord.x,u_texCoord.y * aspect1));
                //pixelCol = texture2D(u_image, vec2(u_texCoord.x,u.texCoord.y );
                // get distance from center of background gradient
                dist = distance(gradCenter,u_texCoord) / 0.707;
                // use dist to caculate the background gradient
                pixelCol += (backDark - backLight) * dist + backLight;
                // add the big ring colour to the background. mouse is the center of big ring
                pixelCol += clamp((1.0-distance(mouse,u_texCoord)) * 345.0 - 270.5 ,0.0,1.0) * ringCol;
                // add the second rign colour to the background colour. secondRing is location of second ring
                pixelCol += clamp((1.0-distance(secondRing,u_texCoord)) * 29.0 - 27. ,0.0,1.0) * ringCol;

                gl_FragColor = pixelCol; // set the fragment to the colour caculated
            }`
    }
}
var firstRun = true;
function webGLRender(){
    var gl = webGL.gl;
    if(firstRun ){
        firstRun = false;
        gl.uniform4f(gl.locs.backDark, 0,0,0,1)
        gl.uniform4f(gl.locs.backLight, 0.3,0.5,0.8,1)
        gl.uniform4f(gl.locs.ringCol, 0.1,0.1,0.38,0.41)
        gl.uniform2f(gl.locs.lightLoc, 0.5,0.0);
    }
    gl.uniform2f(gl.locs.mouse, mouse.x / w,mouse.y / h);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    ctx.drawImage(webGL,0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
function createImageAndStartWebGL(){
    var image = document.createElement("canvas");
    image.width = canvas.width;
    image.height = canvas.height;
    image.ctx = image.getContext("2d");
    image.ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    image.ctx.font = "48px arial";
    image.ctx.textAlign = "center";
    image.ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    image.ctx.fillText("WebGL & Canvas 2D demo",canvas.width/2,48);
    image.ctx.font = "16px arial";
    image.ctx.fillText("WebGL fragment shader processing 2D canvas image, then render back to 2D canvas.",canvas.width/2,66);
    firstRun = true;
    startWebGL(image);
}
// Add the setup to the debounced resize
onresize = createImageAndStartWebGL;

// start it all happening
resizeCanvas(); 
mouse.start(canvas,true); 
window.addEventListener("resize",resizeCanvas); 
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

Comment: How can I be, if I need to generate a lot of balls? I want this effect is achieved http://huaban.com/pins/604178757/

Comment: @Fulrus You will need a webGL 2D particle FX, or can be done with a feedback texture but would be very tricky and may not work well on all machines. webGL particles would be the best solution or even just in 2D canvas will work just fine.